# Удалить директорию Yii

Tags: php, yii

При создании поста, на сервер загружаются файлы, как при удалении удалить и директорию и файлы, и почистить таблицу базы данных?

Пробовал написать `findAllByAttributes(array('post_id'=>$id))`, id это id удаляемой записи, post_id это принадлежность  файла к посту, но что то не удаляет

Answer (score 1):

Загружаемые файлы удаляться не будут, модель ведь не содержит сведений о загружаемых файлах!

Перед удалением записи нужно просто зачиститься, самый простой пример

```
class GHelpers {
    public static function removeDirectory($dir) {
        if ($files = glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*')) {
            foreach ($files as $_file) {
                is_dir($_file) ? self::removeDirectory($dir) : unlink($_file);
            }
        }

        rmdir($dir);

    }

}

class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function actionDelete($id) {
        $model = Model::model()->findByPk($id);

        if ($model) {
            $dir = $model->getPathToFiles();
            GHelpers::removeDirectory($dir);
            $model->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Я все файлы сохраняю в каталоге, имя которого соответствует id записи, потом полностью удаляю каталог со всем содержимым. Надеюсь, это натолкнет вас на мысль в зависимости от вашей реализации.